# Js function argument depend upon the submitted value in EJS

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express, ejs

I am building an express app. I have a drop-down whose submitted value is passed to `users.js` and initiates a mongodb query. Then, result of that query is passed back to ejs and  becomes an argument of a script function.

The problem is I want that function to be called when I click on Submit. (I can afford the delay in rendering of page).

Right now, I have two buttons, one for submit and one for calling that function.

`index2.ejs`

```
    <form action="/users/details" method="POST">
      <fieldset>
      <select required class="selectpicker" name="selectpicker">
            <!-- options -->
        </select>
        
      <input type="submit" id="submit-form" />
      </fieldset>
  </form>


  <button onclick="popu(<%= JSON.stringify(coun) %>);">blue</button>
```

and `users.js`

```
router.get("/index2", function(req, res, next) {

  (async function() {
      count = await funcoun(coll); // a mongodb query
      res.render("index2", {title: 'some data', userdataa: a, imgsrc : coll, coun : count});
    }) ();
});

router.post("/details", function(req, res, next) {
    coll = req.body.selectpicker;
    res.redirect("/users/index2");
})
```

So, basically I want the form to pass value (of coll) to express, calculation of `count`, calling of function with this value, and then rendering the page.

Currently, calculation of `count` is done on basis of old value, and when `blue` button is clicked then present value.

I am confused that if I put `onclick` in submit button, what will it do since coun is not yet calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body onload = "popu(<%= JSON.stringify(coun) %>);">
```

solved the issue